# Python: pynhd package installation problem

Tags: python

I'm quite new to programming and I am struggling with package installation. I am trying to utilize the hyriver/pynhd package from github https://github.com/hyriver/pynhd. I am using PythonWin 3.7.11 [MSC v.1927 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32. I am trying to access the pynhd package by using import pynhd as nhd. However, when I try to run it, it says:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\pynhd-main\tests\test_pynhd.py", line 10, in <module>
    import pynhd as nhd
  File "C:\pynhd-main\pynhd\pynhd.py", line 4, in <module>
    import async_retriever as ar
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'async_retriever'
```

I thought that I had successfully installed async_retriever through the python cmd prompt on my computer but it still is not found. To install async_retriever I used pip install async_retriever. Might anyone have any suggestions?
My end goal is to utilize the HyRiver application in conjunction with ArcGIS.

Comment: how did you install async_retriever?

Comment: Please, share the command you used to install async_retriever

Comment: I used pip install async-retriever